# Pygtk : i would like an example of creating a dialog box (instantiate, run, hide) , mine doesn't disappear after OK

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, dialog

Is there any clear example of how to use message Dialog box ? i tried to implement mine but it crashes the program. When it comes up and i click OK, it doesn't disappear, it becomes a little tiny window still hanging in the middle of the screen, that leaves me no option but CTRL-Z.

I am using glade to read my file, the glade file has the main window and other small windows some of which are window plots and others are Message dialog boxes.

Just a pseudcode is helpful

again, i have a main class, which retrieves all the objects that are needed from the glade file, then class the appropriate class handler signals.

Comment: can somebody help ...i'd appreciate it

Comment: Does this [example](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/dialogs/) help you?